# How do I route 500 errors to a different file than /public/500.html in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, routes

I have a rails app in which I would like /500 to route to a regular page. How do I configure the app so that when 500 errors occur, the app does not look for the error page at /500.html but rather at some other filename I specify?

I understand how to make custom error pages. My concern is around at what route those pages are reached. I do not want [root]/500 to go to an error page. I want the /500 page to live somewhere else, and am hoping to handle that within my rails app rather than through external config.

Comment: https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages

Comment: I understand how to make custom error pages. My concern is around at what route those pages are reached. I do not want [root]/500 to go to an error page. I want the /500 page to live somewhere else, and am hoping to handle that within my rails app rather than through external config.